# Bootstrap CSS - Float Image Beside List

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am trying to get an image to float beside of an unordered list.

I have the following HTML:

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-1"><img id="droid-logo" alt="" src="/templates/notthedroidyouarelookingfor/images/ntdyalf-logo.png"></div>
              <div class="col-md-2"><ul class="nav menu nav-pills">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="item-102"><a href="/index.php/about-us">About</a></li>
<li class="item-106"><a href="/index.php/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
<li class="item-114"><a href="/index.php/troubleshooting">Troubleshooting</a></li></ul>
</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </header>
```

And my CSS:

> ## droid-logo {
>
> ```
> float: left;
> height: 20%;
> margin: 10px;
> width: 20%; }
> ```
>
> ## header ul.menu {
>
> ```
> border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
> display: block;
> float: right;
> margin: 0 10px;
> padding: 0;
> text-align: left;
> width: 70%; }
> ```

The actual website is here:
http://notthedroidyouarelookingfor.com/

I don't understand why the image is below the menu.

Comment: `bootsrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css` is missing and  change `col-md-1` and `col-md-1`  to `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` it hast to be `12`.

Comment: Well, to start with, it's pretty messy. You don't seem to be using Bootstrap at all. Include Bootstraps jQuery and CSS files, without it's useless. [More about Bootstrap here](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

the `<ul class="nav menu nav-pills">` has the css property `position: absolute;`.

This prevents the menu to float.

Try to make the position relative and then try again with float (maybe you have to float the menu left).